# How to obtain the last inserted auto increment id using PDO library?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that of course has a unique id for each entry.

How can I retrieve that id when I do a simple insert using this query string:

```
"INSERT INTO lion_is_foob (id_user, title, url, domain, tag, favicon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

The column name is called `id` for the auto increment.

Because an insert so commonly creates an auto ID can I retrieve this at the same time.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the ID of the inserted row? Or the next available auto-incremented ID?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking for getting the last inserted id, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://php.net/mysql_insert_id or http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id (depending on which set of MySQL functions you're using).

Comment: Really? Yours is two function calls, mine is one. ;)

Comment: it's always two, you have to do the insert and you have to pull the id, you can't do both at once.

Comment: It's three with the variant you suggested (in the comment you deleted): insert, select the last insert ID, fetch result of that.

Comment: I don't know PDO very well, but it probably has its own variation on `mysqli_insert_id`.

Comment: ... snap ... that was in the duplicate.